# What TI season did we start getting an Aegis replica

Tags: dota-2

I was wondering what season of TI (The International) did Valve start releasing a replica of the Aegis? Did it start in season one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first year a person could receive a replica Aegis was **TI5**.

International Compendiums were available since TI3, but the first year the [Aegis reward](https://dota2.gamepedia.com/The_International_Compendium_2015#Rewards_Chart) was available was in 2015 with TI5. Here's the [official blog post](http://blog.dota2.com/2015/07/the-collectors-aegis-of-champions/) announcing it.

[image]